# SharePoint linq query to retrieve specific columns from a list

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

I'm using the SharePoint Client Object Model to query lists in Sharepoint and need to create the Linq queries dynamically in a helper assembly.

How do I create the following from a list<string> of column names containing "Id","Title","LinkFileName","Status" ?

```
context.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(  
  item => item["Id"],  
  item => item["Title"],  
  item => item["LinkFilename"],  
  item => item["Status"]  
));
```

Answer (score 4):

a BIG thank you to Manvir for his post that solved my problem:

http://www.manvir.net/invalidqueryexpressionexception-the-query-expression-is-not-supported/

Replace the `ClientContext.Load` with `ClientContext.LoadQuery` that does support runtime-built expressions.

```
private static Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>[] CreateListItemLoadExpressions(List<string> viewFields)
{
   List<Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>> expressions = new List<Expression<Func<ListItem, object>>>();
   foreach (string viewFieldEntry in viewFields)
   {
      string fieldInternalName = viewFieldEntry;
      Expression<Func<ListItem, object>> retrieveFieldDataExpression = listItem => listItem[fieldInternalName];
      expressions.Add(retrieveFieldDataExpression);
   }
   return expressions.ToArray();
}
```